# Reading every 10 lines using a BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Is there a way of reading, say, every 10 lines from a `.txt` file using a `BufferedReader`? At the moment my `BufferedReader` is reading every line, splitting the different values and storing them in an array list; which is then used elsewhere in my program.

Comment: are your lines a fixed size?

Comment: yes they are a fixed size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to read all the lines you don't want, then read the line you do want.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
int index = 10;
while (lineNumber < index - 1)
    {
        lineNumber++;
        br.readLine();
    }
String lineYouWant = br.readLine();
if (lineYouWant.isEmpty()) br.close();
// Do stuff with lineYouWant
br.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) which is intended for this very purpose:

```
LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);
ArrayList<String> goodLines = new ArrayList<String>();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   if ((reader.getLineNumber()+1) % 10 == 0) {
       goodLines.add(line);
   }
}
```

Comment: The OP asked specifically for an answer with a `BufferedReader`.

Comment: If you look at the [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) javadocs, you'll see that it inherits from [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), @syb0rg

Comment: OP should post as to his feelings, not you.

Comment: It's called interpreting the question. And I quote, "using a buffered reader?".

Comment: By my interpretation (and standard OO parlance), a LineNumberReader **is a** BufferedReader, because it is on the former's inheritance hierarchy. And if you want to discuss further, invite me to a chat with you.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a buffered reader is to make reading logical units like lines easy.  Reading multiple lines would complicate your code and not provide a great performance boost since the buffered reader is already reading large blocks of data into its buffer.

Edit: Since your records are fixed size you could use a lower level reader and just read the amount of bytes required.

Comment: The OP did not ask for advice about `BufferedReader`s, so this does not answer the question.

Comment: @sy Odd, your post says basically the same thing, "do it iteratively"

Comment: My answer has nothing in common with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your lines are the same size you could look at the [skip()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#skip%28long%29) method in the BufferedReader.  You would basically read a line and then skip 10 * lineSize and read the next line, etc...